# Show $\exists$ $n_0$ such that for $n>n_0$, $\varphi_n([0,1])\subseteq \Omega$ and $\varphi_n \cong \varphi$.

Tags: complex-analysis

**Problem 1:** $\Omega$ open, $\varphi:[0,1]\to\Omega$ is a closed path, define $\varphi_n:[0,1]\to\Omega$ to be linear on $\left[\dfrac{j-1}{n},\dfrac{j}{n}\right]$, $\varphi_n\left(\dfrac{j}{n}\right)=\varphi\left(\dfrac{j}{n}\right)$. Show $\exists$ $n_0$ such that for $n>n_0$, $\varphi_n([0,1])\subseteq \Omega$ and $\varphi_n \cong \varphi$  (i.e. $\cong$ is notation for homotopy).

**Proof of $\varphi\cong \varphi_n$**: Since $\varphi$ is a closed path, $\varphi(0)=\varphi(1)$. We construct 
\begin{gather*}
H: [0,1]\times [0,1]\to\Omega \\
H(s,t)=s\varphi(t)+(1-s)\varphi_n(t)
\end{gather*}
where $s,t\in [0,1]$. We need to verify the conditions of a homotopy

- $H(0,t)=0\cdot\varphi(t)+(1-0)\varphi_n(t)=\varphi_n(t)$
- $H(1,t)=1\cdot\varphi(t)+(1-1)\varphi_n(t)=\varphi(t)$
- $H(s,0)=s\varphi(0)+(1-s)\varphi_n(0)=s\varphi(0)+(1-s)\varphi(0)=s\varphi(1)+(1-s)\varphi(1)=s\varphi(1)+(1-s)\varphi_n(1)=H(s,1)$

Hence $\varphi\cong\varphi_n$. **Is this proof correct?**

**Also, how would I show that $\varphi_n([0,1])\subseteq\Omega$?**

**Problem 2:** If $\varphi$ rectifiable, $f\in\mathcal{O}(\Omega)$, then $\int\limits_{\varphi_n} f \to \int\limits_{\varphi} f$. (independent of $n$)

**Doesn't this follow immediately from Problem 1?**

Comment: What is $\Omega$?

Comment: $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{C}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing some important points. You have not even taken n large enough. You have to show that $\phi_n$ has range in $\Omega$ but more importantly you have to make sure that $H$ also has its range in $\Omega$. Only then you can say that $\phi_n$ and $\phi$ are homotopic in $\Omega$. Do prove that let $\delta =d(\phi ([0,1]),\mathbb C - \Omega)$. this is a positive number. Now that fact that $\phi$ is uniformly continuous implies that $\phi_n \to \phi$ uniformly. If $|\phi_n (t) \phi (t)| < \delta$ it is easy to see that $\phi_n ([0,1])$ is contained in $\Omega$. A similar argument shows that H also takes values in $\Omega$. (I will give more details if you ask).

Comment: I would greatly appreciate it if you can show at least show the range of $\phi_n $ in $\Omega $. also does problem two come immediately from the first problem?

Comment: Suppose $\phi_n(t) \in \mathbb C - \Omega$. Then $\delta \leq |\phi (t) - \phi_n (t)|$ by definition of $\delta$. There exist $j$ such that $\frac {j-1} n \leq t \leq \frac j n$. Now $\phi_n (t) =\phi_n (j/n) -n (j/n -t) (\phi (j/n)-\phi ((j-1)/n)$ since $\phi_n$ is linear in $[(j-1)/n, j/n]$. Now, by uniform continuity $|\phi (j/n)-\phi ((j-1)/n)|$ and  $|\phi (t)-\phi ((j-1)/n)|$ can both be made small by choosing n large. Get a contradiction from this. The proof for H is similar. Just fix s and replace $\phi_n (t)$ by $H(s,t)$ in the argument.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for providing this proof. Also, from Problem 1 do we get Problem 2?

Comment: Yes, 1) implies 2).